# Steady State of a Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences, steady-state

Consider the following equation,

$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, with $f(x)= x\exp(\frac{2-x}{3})$

Calculate the two steady states $x^*_1$ and $x^*_2$ of the above map.

So based on what I've learnt to find the steady state you do the following:

Solve the equation $x^*=x^*\exp(\frac{2-x^*}{3})$ for $x^*$ and you will find the steady state(s).

However when attempting to do this myself I found only one steady state of $x^*=2$ which can't be correct as the question indicates there will be two solutions.. however I'm not sure where my knowledge gap is particularly.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You have assumed $x^*\neq 0$ to simplify!! Maybe $x^*=0$ is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 1):

2 is indeed one of the steady states, and to find it you probably did something akin to the following: Divide both sides by $x^*$:
$$x^*=x^*e^{\frac{2-x}{3}}$$ $$1=e^\frac{2-x}{3}$$Then taking the logarithm $$0=\frac{2-x}{3}$$ and so $x=2$. However, in the first step I had to make an assumption about $x^*$. What was it?